# Split batch file commands into multiple lines in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am a newbie in writing batch files and need help.

I want to do the following tasks using a single batch file.

1) Start cmd
2) Change directory to C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MRO\R-3.3.0\bin
3) Run a R script there

I know I can achieve this if I write the command as follows :

```
    cmd.exe /K "cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MRO\R-3.3.0\bin && Rscript BlowerHealthIntegration.R 0.753975708353173 0.16874738612188295 0.028476842398414307 -0.014617814348478057 0.6436494038934525 0.17659988446055574 0.007223245126697915 -0.014617814348478057"
```

But the main problem is I have to write everything in a single line.

How can I split them into separate lines ?

Say I want to write something like this

```
    cmd.exe
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MRO\R-3.3.0\bin
    Rscript BlowerHealthIntegration.R 0.753975708353173 0.16874738612188295 0.028476842398414307 -0.014617814348478057 0.6436494038934525 0.17659988446055574 0.007223245126697915 -0.014617814348478057
```

This is like entering each command after pressing enter. How can I achieve this in Windows 7 x64 bit.

Comment: Note that a Batch.bat file is executed by the `cmd.exe` processor _automatically_. In other words, you usually don't need to invoke `cmd.exe` in a Batch file (unless you are using some advanced method); just put the desired commands in the .bat file, one per line...

Answer (score 1):

Give a try for this code and tell me the results :

```
@echo off
CD /D "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\MRO\R-3.3.0\bin\"
Rscript "BlowerHealthIntegration.R 0.753975708353173 0.16874738612188295 0.028476842398414307 -0.014617814348478057 0.6436494038934525 0.17659988446055574 0.007223245126697915 -0.014617814348478057"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first problem is that it instantly turns off.

So I added timeout 25 at end to make the output visible a bit longer.

But another error states that "No such file or directory" . But the file is there.

Comment: Please remove or comment out the `@echo off` line. Then, copy and paste the output when running the script at the cmd shell prompt. Post it in the question, not in a comment like this.